# Using increment to loop a function

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm using for loop, to do a certain function while incrementing the items in array

```
   $scope.newGetbloodcomponent = ['a','a','a']
   $scope.newBloodgroup = "A_positive";
 for(index = 0, len =  $scope.newGetbloodcomponent.length; index < len; index++){ 
            var userObject = {}; 
            var index,len;
            userObject.blood_component = $scope.newGetbloodcomponent[index];
            userObject.blood_group = $scope.newBloodgroup;

            Bloodinventory.addDecreaseinventory(userObject).then(function(data) {});

            }
```

Then in my api.js I want to increment every items in the array: So I want to find and increment a certain document in mongodb using array ['a','a','a'], but this only increment once, here is what I did:

```
        var newValue = 1;
        var newGetbloodcomponent = req.body.blood_component; 
        var newBloodgroup = req.body.blood_group; 


        Bloodinventory.find({$and: [ {blood_component : { $in : newGetbloodcomponent}} ,{blood_group: { $in :newBloodgroup}}] }, function(err, bloodinventoryDocs) {

            for(let bloodinventory of bloodinventoryDocs) {
                bloodinventory.num_stock = bloodinventory.num_stock + newValue ;                        
                bloodinventory.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err); 
                    } else {
                        console.log('success'); 
                    }
                });
            }  
        });
```

My problem here is that, when using same items in array [a,a,a], it is read as once so it only increment once, instead of incrementing three times

Sample Document:

```
_id:5c743847083f66292481c1b3
blood_group:A_positive
chapter:5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b
num_stock:12          //this should be 15 if the array is ['a','a','a']
blood_component:a
reserved_stock:0
remaining_stock:0
blood_type:A
```

Comment: any help there, I really need to finish this, for my defense tomorrow

Comment: please someone I really need to finish it

Comment: Could you please specify elements in `userObject.blood_component` in your first function?

Comment: Please share your schema "Bloodinventory" or document where you want to increment.

Comment: updated my question, I hope I can finish this problem now

Comment: any help please, I still cant figure it out